# Calculating the directional derivative and the tangent to this function

Tags: multivariable-calculus

My first post, if something is missing or not according to etiquette please tell me.

I have to calculate the directional derivative of the function $f(x,y) = 3x^2y^2+x+8y$ in the point $(2,1)$ to $(1,2)$. I also have to calculate the tangent to this line in $(2,1)$

So I first calculated the partial derivatives to $x$ and $y$, this gave me $6xy^2+1$ and $6yx^2+8$.
Then to calculate the directional derivative I did the following:
$(6xy^2+1) \times 1/\sqrt{5} + (6yx^2 + 8) \times 1/\sqrt{5}$
I then filled in the point $(1,2)$ getting an answer of $70/\sqrt{5}$.

Now I am not sure if my method to calculate the directional derivative was right, but I do not know how to go further to calculate the tangent to this line in $(2,1)$.

Can anyone help with that please?

Comment: When you write “this line”, which line is that?

Comment: [Here's a MathJax tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) :)

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos This line means the curve, sorry I translated it too directly.

Comment: Thanks for the link @Shaun I had sadly enough already written the post before thinking damn I thought stack exchange supported LaTeX? And then I found a link explaining it but I decided to post it as is, since there arent many big calculations being done. Favorited that page though, very handy

Comment: Ans which curve is that?

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos it is the curve f(x,y). Sorry if I wasn't clear enough.

Comment: But $f$ is a function, not a curve.

Comment: Huh, maybe I misinterpreted the question. The question only says "calculate the tangent to the curve in the point (2,1)". Does it mean that I have to calculate the tangent of the directional derivative?

Comment: I have no idea. It's your question, not mine. Perhaps that it's the curve $f(x,y)=22$, since $(2,1)$ belongs to it.

Comment: I'm not sure myself either, i'll try to check some exercises and see if I see a familiar exercise that shows me the method then. I haven't seen any but ill try.

Comment: @AnaS.H. Do you really think that the idea is to find the tangent line to a line segment?